# How to switch tty1 from GUI in 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: 18.04, gui

In my PC, Ubuntu 18.04.4 was installed. When I shut it down last time, it did shutdown perfectly. But now, after turning it on, TTY1 came up and I can't switch to GUI mode using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use the command `startx` to open GUI. Did you edit any configuration files?

Comment: well, it has been solved. My GUI was crashed. So, i have to reinstall  it.